# Creating card objects for the card game war in Python

Tags: python

So I have to re-create the card game War using card objects. The problem I am running into is how to compare the two lists of card objects to see which one is bigger. I have not tried anything to compare the two lists because I really do not even know where to begin. I need to compare which one is bigger and give points to that list/person for winning. An ace is a 1 but that beats a king which is 13 I have the overload methods in the class because I know that is where to start with that, but here is what I have so far:

```
import random
class War:
    def __init__(self):
        randomCard = random.randint(1,13)
        self._cNumber = randomCard
        randomSuit = random.randint(1,4)
        self._cSuit = randomSuit

        if self._cSuit == 1:
            self._cSuit = "H"
        elif self._cSuit == 2:
            self._cSuit = "S"
        elif self._cSuit == 3:
            self._cSuit = "C"
        elif self._cSuit == 4:
            self._cSuit = "D"


    def getNumber(self):
        return self._cNumber

    def getSuit(self):
        return self._cSuit

    def __str__(self):
        if self._cNumber > 1 and self._cNumber < 11:
            return str(self._cNumber) + self._cSuit
        elif self._cNumber == 1:
            return "A" + self._cSuit
        elif self._cNumber == 11:
            return "J" + self._cSuit
        elif self._cNumber == 12:
            return "Q" + self._cSuit
        elif self._cNumber == 13:
            return "K" + self._cSuit

    def __gt__(self,other):
        if self._cNumber == 1:
            self._cNumber = 14
        if other._cNumber == 1:
            other._cNumber = 14

        if self._cNumber > other._cNumber:
            return True


    def __lt__(self,other):
        if self._cNumber == 1:
            self._cNumber = 14
        if other._cNumber == 1:
            other._cNumber = 14

        if self._cNumber < other._cNumber:
            return True
        return False

    def __eq__(self,other):
        if self._cNumber == 1:
            self._cNumber = 14
        if other._cNumber == 1:
            other._cNumber = 14

        if self._cNumber == other._cNumber:
            return True
        return False

cardList1 = []
cardList2 = []

list1C1 = War()
list1C2 = War()
list1C3 = War()
list1C4 = War()
list1C5 = War()
cardList1.append(list1C1)
cardList1.append(list1C2)
cardList1.append(list1C3)
cardList1.append(list1C4)
cardList1.append(list1C5)

list2C1 = War()
list2C2 = War()
list2C3 = War()
list2C4 = War()
list2C5 = War()
cardList2.append(list2C1)
cardList2.append(list2C2)
cardList2.append(list2C3)
cardList2.append(list2C4)
cardList2.append(list2C5)

print("Player 1:")
for x in range(5):
    print(cardList1[x])

print("Player 2:")
for x in range(5):
    print(cardList2[x])
```

Comment: Welcome to So. Please take the time to read [ask].  What is the question?

Comment: "The problem I am running into is how to compare the two lists of card objects to see which one is bigger." - bigger how? Which list is longer? Or, if they are the same length, which cards are "stronger"? If you can clarify that I could help you.

Comment: I need to compare which one is bigger and give points to that list/person for winning. An ace is a 1 but that beats a king which is 13

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
'''
Class that models a standard playing card.
Objects of this type will have a number between 1 and 13 (inclusive) and a suit (Spade, Heart, Club or Diamond).
Models the card game War by comparing two card objects and determining the winner based on the bigger card number
'''
import random
class War:
    def __init__(self):
        '''
        Constructs the card number and suit of the card object and assigns random values within playing card range. Also accounts for cards higher than 10 going into face cards.
        '''
        randomCard = random.randint(1,13)
        self._cNumber = randomCard
        randomSuit = random.randint(1,4)
        self._cSuit = randomSuit

        if self._cSuit == 1:
            self._cSuit = "H"
        elif self._cSuit == 2:
            self._cSuit = "S"
        elif self._cSuit == 3:
            self._cSuit = "C"
        elif self._cSuit == 4:
            self._cSuit = "D"


    def getNumber(self):
        '''
        Accessor method that returns the number on the card object
        '''
        return self._cNumber

    def getSuit(self):
        '''
        Accessor method that returns the suit on the card object
        '''
        return self._cSuit

    def __str__(self):
        '''
        Allows for the user to print out the card objects values instead of a memory location
        '''
        if self._cNumber > 1 and self._cNumber < 11:
            return str(self._cNumber) + self._cSuit
        elif self._cNumber == 1:
            return "A" + self._cSuit
        elif self._cNumber == 11:
            return "J" + self._cSuit
        elif self._cNumber == 12:
            return "Q" + self._cSuit
        elif self._cNumber == 13:
            return "K" + self._cSuit

    def __gt__(self,other):
        '''
        Overloading the greater than operator to use for comparing the card objects
        '''
        if self._cNumber == 1:
            self._cNumber = 14
        if other._cNumber == 1:
            other._cNumber = 14

        if self._cNumber > other._cNumber:
            return True
        return False


    def __lt__(self,other):
        '''
        Overloading the less than operator to use for comparing the card objects
        '''
        if self._cNumber == 1:
            self._cNumber = 14
        if other._cNumber == 1:
            other._cNumber = 14

        if self._cNumber < other._cNumber:
            return True
        return False

    def __eq__(self,other):
        '''
        Overloading the equals to operator to use for comparing the card objects
        '''
        if self._cNumber == 1:
            self._cNumber = 14
        if other._cNumber == 1:
            other._cNumber = 14

        if self._cNumber == other._cNumber:
            return True
        return False
#Create two lists that will be used for storing the card objects
cardList1 = []
cardList2 = []

#Creating 5 card objects for each list then appending them to the list
list1C1 = War()
list1C2 = War()
list1C3 = War()
list1C4 = War()
list1C5 = War()
cardList1.append(list1C1)
cardList1.append(list1C2)
cardList1.append(list1C3)
cardList1.append(list1C4)
cardList1.append(list1C5)

list2C1 = War()
list2C2 = War()
list2C3 = War()
list2C4 = War()
list2C5 = War()
cardList2.append(list2C1)
cardList2.append(list2C2)
cardList2.append(list2C3)
cardList2.append(list2C4)
cardList2.append(list2C5)

#Prints out the card object values such as suit and number on the card
print("Player 1:")
for x in range(5):
    print(cardList1[x])

print("Player 2:")
for x in range(5):
    print(cardList2[x])

#Initializes point system for the game of War
Player1Points = 0
Player2Points = 0

#Loops through the lists comparing the two card objects to each other and determining whether Player 1: Wins, Ties, or Loses
for x in range(5):
    if War.__gt__(cardList1[x], cardList2[x]) == True:
        Player1Points += 1
        print("Player 1 Wins")
    elif War.__eq__(cardList1[x], cardList2[x]) == True:
        print("No points awarded. Tie.")
    else:
        Player2Points += 1
        print("Player 2 Wins")
    print("Player 1 points: ",Player1Points," Player 2 Points: ",Player2Points)

#Determines the winner of the game based on the number of points each player had
if Player1Points > Player2Points:
    print("Player 1 Wins the game")
elif Player2Points > Player1Points:
    print("Player 2 Wins the game")
else:
    print("It is a tie")
```

Comment: you are breaking the DRY principle, continually repeating yourself.. you should make another function to put this code into so you do not repeat yourself.. which is also why i said you should make other classes.. you could learn a lot by refactoring your code

Answer (score 1):

For overloading card methods for a War Game you only need to be concerned with the rank of the card and not the suit, the following may work for that..

```
def cmp(self, other):
    if self.rank > other.rank: return 1
    if self.rank < other.rank: return -1
    return 0

def __eq__(self, other):
    return self.cmp(other) == 0

def __le__(self, other):
    return self.cmp(other) <= 0

def __ge__(self, other):
    return self.cmp(other) >= 0

def __gt__(self, other):
    return self.cmp(other) > 0

def __lt__(self, other):
    return self.cmp(other) < 0

def __ne__(self, other):
    return self.cmp(other) != 0
```

Also you may want to implement a `Card` class, `Deck` class, and `Hand` class before you write the `War` class.  At least a `Card` class is necessary to utilize the previously posted code as it takes in two objects (Cards) as parameters

Comment: I actually figured it out myself on this one and you do not need to create more than one class.

Comment: i guess thats true. but you really **should** create some other classes to modularize your code.. i mean that is if you want to do an appropriate OOP design methodology approach.  as you can see, there is a ton of unnecessary code after the class definition, this is because your code is improperly encapsulated, it is all put together in one class which is very messy and leads to smelly code